# opencv find orb/keypoint x and y

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencv, object-detection, detection

I want to find the x and y axis of all the green orbs in the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/r0v82sej/15/

I am able to do this with hough lines, but not yet orbs/keypoints: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/de6/tutorial_js_houghlines.html

```
function setPhoto(){

    var imgpath = 'https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/9/d/9d3386e4-bbd6-4756-b29d-f55619e98d0d.jpg?1562820948';

    var canvasid = 'canvas1';
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasid);
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = imgpath;
    base_image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

    base_image.onload = function(){

        canvas.setAttribute("width", base_image.width);
        canvas.setAttribute("height", base_image.height);

        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, base_image.width, base_image.height);

        addOrbs(canvas, canvasid);

    };

}

function addOrbs(currcanvas, canvasid){

    var corners = [];
    var refCols = currcanvas.width;
    var refRows= currcanvas.height;

    var orb = new cv.ORB(5000);

    let src = cv.imread(canvasid);
    refGray = convertImageToGray(src)

    var noArray = new cv.Mat();
    refDescr = new cv.Mat();
    refKeyPts = new cv.KeyPointVector();

    orb.detectAndCompute(refGray, noArray, refKeyPts, refDescr);
    
    // initialize reference image corners for warping
    corners[0] = new cv.Point( 0, 0 );
    corners[1] = new cv.Point( refCols, 0 );
    corners[2] = new cv.Point( refCols, refRows );
    corners[3] = new cv.Point( 0, refRows );

    let out = new cv.Mat();
    
    cv.drawKeypoints(refGray, refKeyPts, out, [0, 255, 0, 255]);

    //console.log('out', out);

    cv.imshow(canvasid, out);
    refGray.delete();
    
}

function convertImageToGray(img) {
  let dst = new cv.Mat();
  cv.cvtColor(img, dst, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
  return dst;
}
```

Comment: PS: the jQuery tag is not necessary - You're using plain JS in your samples

Comment: You have uninstantiated (global) variables `refDescr` , `refKeyPts`, `refGray`, etc

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan jquery and javascript are silmilar enough that I found it necessary. opencv is often associated with python, and I want to filter that out as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: https://scottsuhy.com/2021/02/01/image-alignment-feature-based-in-opencv-js-javascript/

```
 for (let i = 0; i < refKeyPts.size(); i++) {
          console.log("keypoints1: [",i,"]", refKeyPts.get(i).pt.x, refKeyPts.get(i).pt.y);
          
        }
```